# Filter a list based on some values and again filter the result on first output

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I currently have a scenario where I have a List and I filter based on the values inside this and I need to filter again based on the outcome.

```
for (Employee emp : data.getEmployees()) {
    if (emp.getAge() > 30) {
        for (Position position : emp.getPositions()) {
            if (position.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Manager")) {

                return position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it using Java 8 stream?

```
data.getEmployees().stream().filter(emp -> emp.getAge>30)
```

Not sure on how to use it further. As this will just result in the list of employees I just want the list of employee with position as manager

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to either get the `Position`s or a stream of those:

```
data.getEmployees().stream()
.filter(emp -> emp.getAge>30)
.flatMap(emp->emp.getPositions().stream())
.filter(pos->"Manager". equalsIgnoreCase (pos.getName()))
```

`flatMap` creates a new stream containing all elements of the streams found by the parameter of all elements.

Or to get all employees that are managers:

```
data.getEmployees().stream()
.filter(emp -> emp.getAge>30)
.filter(emp->emp.getPositions().stream().anyMatch(pos->
    "Manager". equalsIgnoreCase (pos.getName())
))
```

It just creates a new stream of the positions of all employees and tests if there is one with the name `Manager`.

If you want to e.g. get it as list, you can just append `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.